# Site upgrate: update+https vs 2 stage migration

Tags: wordpress, https, migration, redirect

Newbie question here.

I'm about to rebuild a site for a client, moving from old CMS to WordPress (with updated IA) and HTTP => HTTPS.

My question is, what is the best approach to do this that is the least complex? Which will introduce the least opportunity for errors?

**Option A:**

- Port to Wordpress and migrate to HTTPS in one massive leap.

or

**Option B:**

1. Port to Wordpress and set up 301 redirects for any retired
   paths/assets etc.
2. Implement SSL certificates, etc, and bulk 301
   redirects from HTTP to HTTPS (eg. *Redirect 301 /
   https://www.newsite.com*)

Many thanks for any help on this.

Cheers,
Tys.

Answer (score 0):

Migrating old CMS to WP is not easy if you are an inexperienced. Why? For the following reasons: DB, New CMS Management, Style, Support.
So if we are better off separating tasks into smaller tasks and completing them so that things get easier. Make it the right choice for what you are have.
I will say a few things that I think you should consider before you work.

- Keep site live and backup after create new site dev when check all ok i'll move site dev to site live.
- Check CMS old that supports transferring whole DB or style to WP.
- For Ecommerce projects you need to pay attention to migrate your product so consider the plugin import support data to 2 CMS.
- Carefully refer to the CMS plugin that you want to optimize for migration.

There is no best plan that only works best for you.

HTTPS is a matter of security and SEO, most people use it. The problem of safe migration and to avoid problems, we need to carefully examine the following issues:

- SSL certificates there are 3 ways( free and fees ):

  - Let's Encrypt™ SSL is free but only 3 month so you need to configure it to auto-renew ( auto renew have in cpanel if you use hosting http://prntscr.com/jag1ix but vps we need config auto-renew ). Suggest to use it if your website is a blog and just support for SEO.
  - CloudFlare support SSL free and fees ( Flexible SSL, Full SSL, Full SSL (strict) ) everybody can read https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/
  - For commercial websites and systems that need to be more secure and secure you can purchase separate certificates for domains, prices vary depending on the security level, technical assistance, avoid counterfeit, compensation, ...( Extended validation (EV), Domain validation (DV), Organizational validation (OV) )
- Steps to use in WP:

  - Config SSL in host or VPS ( if use Let's Encrypt™ SSL we only login cpanel after active for domain use, vps we install and config + auto renew )
  - Setting http to https on site WP ( if you use CloudFlare have support ) http://prntscr.com/jagfnq
  - User plugin convert link http -> https http://prntscr.com/jaggf7 or you can change it in db ( be careful ). With hard-coded links you need to change it.
  - Debug: you can http://prntscr.com/jaghu5 and check console tab. If done look like http://i.prntscr.com/ULhCRCXxRl6SRn7lgBSzBA.png

In short, I can not write more fully, I will add it if there is more time tomorrow, hoping to help you.

Comment: Hi Renoug Joni, Thank you for your detailed response. I'm not sure that it helps me to decide which approach to take, but I appreciate your help with these technical implementation details.

Comment: Hi @Tys issue move old CMS to WordPress i'll try update tonight but i see it's option A and B same same because all link dynamically ( It also depends on each person's experience )